# mysql group by order by issue

Tags: php, mysql

My question is:

I have a datebase like this:

```
| from |  to  | time |   text   | read |
| hans | poul | 0916 | hi there |   1  |
| john | poul | 1033 | waz up   |   1  |
| hans | john | 1145 | new text |   0  |
| poul | john | 1219 | message  |   0  |
| poul | hans | 1233 | respond  |   0  |
```

I want an output where every "from" or "to" has 'hans' listed, grouped and order by time like this:

```
poul - 1233 - respond  - 0
john - 1145 - new text - 0
```

Comment: do you want from and to to be 'hans' or either one of it is hans?

Comment: ` poul | 0916 | hi there |   1` why the first row is omitted in your result set? Please explain your output.

Answer (score -1):

Your sql query could be :-

```
select * from `table_name` where (`from` ='hans' or `to` ='hans') group by `from`, `to` order by time desc
```

Post back if you find any difficulties.

Comment: `from` is a reserved word

Comment: @roullie yep yep changed it.

Comment: This looks dodgy to me :-(

Comment: @Strawberry why explain pls.

Comment: Because in a GROUP BY, results of non-aggregated columns are indeterminate.

Comment: @Strawberry  See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c88e/1. i'm getting the results correct but with your answer i'm getting an error.

Comment: Your fiddle is not properly representative of the problem. My solution was missing some punctuation. Fixed.

Comment: Hi Strawberry,

I have tried your code, and I have these issues:
1. If I make a new row with a "from john to hans", it displays a new row instead of group it with the "from hans to john".

2. If I make a new row with "from poul to john" and set the time to "1945" insted of "0916", it displays the "0916" - the first entrie.

Comment: @CitronAutobot please update your question accordingly. My answer is correct for the question originally asked